# Intellij Code Insight for Gradle Init Scripts

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

How can you get IntelliJ's code insight (highlighting, autocomplete etc) to work for a gradle init script like `init.gradle(.kts)`?

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that Intellij will not give you proper code insight for a file that is in a directory of the current project. It will either treat is as a bare groovy/kotlin script, or as a standard build script. If there is a way to get it to work, I just haven't found it yet.

But keeping that in mind, here's how you can get editor support for a gradle `init.gradle(.kts)` script.

#### Method I

1. Place it in the either the `$GRADLE_USER_HOME/`, `$GRADLE_USER_HOME/init.d/`, or `$GRADLE_HOME/init.d/` directory ***after*** you backup or rename any existing scripts there that might have a name conflict.
2. From within the open project in IntelliJ, go to `File -> Open` , select the script file that you just moved.
3. When the popup opens, select the `Open as file` option.

#### Method II

1. From within the open project in IntelliJ, go to `File -> Open` , select any `init.gradle(.kts)` script that is ***not part of the open project***.
2. When the popup opens, select the `Open as file` option.
3. IJ should show a blue bar in the editor pane with an option to `Link Gradle Project`. Following that option will do what it says and give you code insight relative to the linked project.

This probably isn't the ideal solution you would actually like, such as having the file somewhere in the project itself, but IntelliJ really can't properly load information about the script if it isn't in a location that your projects gradle would load it by default. This isn't an issue with IntelliJ, but rather with gradle and how it loads the init scripts.

Comment: Technically, you don't have to copy the file to a specific location, you can open it from anywhere with File -> Open -> Open as File
There is also a YouTrack Issue (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-323996/Gradle-Implement-highlighting-autocompletion-for-Gradle-initialization-scripts-init.gradle) to improve init.gradle editing experience, which you can upvote to raise its' priority for the developers and comment with any specific functionality, you would like to see added.

Comment: @romanv-jb Thanks for the clarification. I did more experimentation to be sure, and I believe the answer could be improved. IJ gives you an option to link a project when you open an init script that is not already on the projects path (such as gradle_home or gradle_user_home), but only if it is not already in a directory under the project.